# Not able to invoke Perl script from Java

Tags: java, perl

I am trying to invoke Perl script from Java but seems like I am not able to do it.

Here is my Perl script which creates a file. It is a simple script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt');
print $fh "My first report generated by perl\n";
close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

Here is my Java code which is invoking above Perl script.

```
package perlfromjava;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class PerlFromJava {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String command = "perl $HOME/Documents/hello.pl";
        System.out.println(command);
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PerlFromJava.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

}
```

When I am running Perl scrip from command like, it is working perfectly but when I am invoking Perl script from Java, report.txt file is not getting created.

Why is it happening?

Thanks

Comment: You should always check whether calls to `open` are successful: `open(my $fh, '>', 'report.txt') or die "Failed to open report.txt: $!";` You can also add `use autodie;` to the top of your Perl script to do these checks automatically.

Comment: Got that. Thanks:) But Is that the problem when I invoke Perl script from Java, report.txt file is not  getting created?

Comment: Could be. Update your Perl script and re-run your Java code to see. If it still doesn't work, you've at least ruled out one possible source of your issue. If `open` fails, the `$!` variable will give the exact reason.

Comment: I'm not sure that `$HOME` will be extrapolated inside the exec call. Try to give the full path without variable instead. Also, better given the full path to perl too.

Comment: I used full path, still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually your code is working .but the problem is the file created by perl is generated in where you run java file.if you are using a ide then file has surely created inside of that project folder .if you search "report.txt" you will find the file.to understand change your perl script to

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open(my $fh, '>', 'C:/Users/Madhawa.se/Desktop/js/report.txt');
print $fh "My first report generated by perl\n";
close $fh;
print "done\n";
```

intead give report.txt give full path where u like to create report.txt file in the perl script .and see it's working.

```
 try {

    String command = "perl C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\js\\mm.pl";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
    if (process.exitValue() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Command Successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Command Failure");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the $HOME variable from the Java `Runtime`. In Java, you could use `System.getenv("HOME")` or the cross-platform [`System.getProperty(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29) to get it, like

```
String command = "perl " + System.getProperty("user.home") 
        + "/Documents/hello.pl";
```

A list of available [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) is included in The Java Tutorials.

**Edit**

Don't forget to wait for the `Process` to complete,

```
try {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    proc.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @user3745870 Edited to add `waitFor`.